# how to decode the information contained in a CryptnetUrlCache file?

Tags: windows

I am looking for the content of a message that was inadvertently deleted and does not exist in the deleted folder.  I need the ability to view contents of both text and email messages.  When I open one of the files in Appdata/LocalLow/Microsoft/CryptnetUrlCache with Notepad, it is encrypted so that I cannot read it.
Thanks,
Kurt Monroe

Comment: Should only see CRL / visited URLs in that file and relevant info should be plaintext. Try running `strings` on the file. Also possibly see http://propellerheadforensics.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/thomson_windows-8-forensic-guide2.pdf

Comment: Thank you.  I will try to learn how to run strings on the file.

Comment: The *Windows 8 Forensic Guide* by Amanda C. F. Thomson (the document that @ssnobody linked to; FYI, it is an 83-page PDF file) has been archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20170624191721/https://propellerheadforensics.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/thomson_windows-8-forensic-guide2.pdf.